# How to translate この正確な瞬間に - 私が生きている

Tags: translation, kanji

Can you help me with this simple translation?

この正確な瞬間に Should be something like *in this very moment* or *at this exact moment*

私が生きている Should be something like *I'm alive*

Is it correct? Can you confirm it?

Comment: you're about right, what in these sentences is troubling you? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kono seikaku na shunkan ni

At this exact moment

watashi ga ikiteru

I am alive

looks like you have the translation pretty accurately done. you could use the word "precise" instead of "exact", but that's a matter of synonymous choices... What you've decided on, works fine.